# Property 'path' does not exist on type 'Location' - Angular (karma) unit test routing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, path, router

I'm trying to do unit test on routes in my angular (v15) project, in my **app.component.spec.ts**.

I want to use the path() method from Location in** my unit test** :

```
  it('navigate to "" redirects to /home page', fakeAsync(()=>{
    router.navigate(['']);
    tick();
    expect(location.path()).toBe('/home'); // doesn't know path method
  })
  )
```

I have imported Location & RouterTesintModule with the routes of my app im my **app.component.spec.ts**:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { routes } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
        ...
      })
      ],
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
      ]

    }).compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });
```

I have this error : **Property 'path' does not exist on type 'Location'**

I saw that usally this problem happened when we don't import Location, but I did.

I expected my test passed, according to what I declared in my **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
...
  { path: "", redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Why can't I use path method or what could I do else to do this test?

Thanks,